# Ionic 3 - How to move content behind disabled(transparent) button

Tags: ionic-framework, button, transparent, floating-action-button

Is there a way to force content behind a disabled button, that is transparent?

[image]

Here is the code:

```
  <ion-fab bottom right #fab1>
     <button tappable ion-fab color="green" class="no-text-transform" (click)="proximo()" [disabled]="!cultivaresForm.valid">
       <ion-icon name="arrow-round-forward"></ion-icon>
       <ion-label>Próximo</ion-label>
     </button>
  </ion-fab>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure to understand what you want to do here, but if you want to apply a style depending on a particular logic you can use ngClass.

i.e. if you want to apply a style to your text when the button is disabled (so when 
`!cultivaresForm.valid`) you can do something like this:

```
<ion-fab bottom right #fab1>
     <button tappable ion-fab color="green" class="no-text-transform" (click)="proximo()" [disabled]="!cultivaresForm.valid">
       <ion-icon name="arrow-round-forward"></ion-icon>
       <ion-label>Próximo</ion-label>
     </button>
  </ion-fab>
<p [ngClass]="{text-behind: !cultivaresForm.valid}">the text you want to put behind</p>
```

You can then define the `text-behind` style in a separate CSS file.